# Multiplying two variables using bit shift operation

Tags: c++, c, unix, bit-manipulation

I have two variables(which are actually elements of two different matrices). For example i want to multiply

```
a[i][k]*b[k][j]
```

using bit manipulation, how can i do that.

I saw references to multiply constants, not variables like 3*2, 3*4, 3*8, etc. But how can i apply same techniques to multiplying variables? If a post on this exist, can you point me to that. Thanks!

Comment: It would be *very inefficient*.  Is there a reason *why* you want to use bit shifting?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have matrix entries of size 100000x1000000. I want to speedup the implementation

Comment: Ah, It's the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).  This can be done, but only if you want your code to be **much** slower.

Comment: Inefficient? I read bit shifting is efficient than direct matrix multiplication. Is it not???

Comment: @JustinCarrey To speed up matrix multiplication, look at low level primitives (like SSE) and faster matrix multiplication algorithms (that do fewer multiplications) and sparse-matrix optimizations (I hope your 100000 x 100000 matrix is mostly zeros...)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit shift multiplication is usable only when multiplying by a power of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16 etc). The multiplication will then be reduced to as single bit shift operation:

```
  x1 = 2^n;
  result = x2 << n;  // This is the same as x2 * x1
```

For arbitrary cases, the most efficient way is to use normal multiplication:

```
a[i][k]*b[k][j]
```

Comment: oh thats too bad! I heard from my professor that multiplication through bit shifting is most efficient. He didn't say anything about multiplying by power of 2.

Comment: @JustinCarrey Your professor should also mention that modern compilers will automatically do the bit shifting when it is more effective.

Comment: I think my problem here is solved. Abandoning the bit shift approach :)

Answer (score 6):

Given two integral variables

```
unsigned X, Y;
```

And given a Commodore 64, Apple ][, or some other architecture that doesn't have its own multiply instruction, this will multiply the numbers.

```
unsigned answer = 0;
while ( X )
{
  answer <<= 1;
  if ( X & 1 )
    answer += Y;
  X >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: Instead of going thru these loops and if's where conditional branches and jumps occur, i think it will be efficient if we multiply them directly

Answer (score 1):

If you're multiplying huge matrices, what matters is an efficient algorithm that has good cache behavior. For C++, check out [the Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). On a modern CPU you can't micro-optimize multiplication of two variables.